# Clearing is not working on my div

Tags: javascript, css

I have a code snippet and I am trying to clear orange div under yellow one. Why is clear:left not working?

http://jsfiddle.net/w5K4j/14/

```
#parent {
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
}

#unknown {
    float:right;
    height:50px;
    width:20px;
    clear:left; /* Shouldn't it make child(orange) div to float under? */
    background-color: yellow
}

#child {
    float:right;
    height:100px;
    width:50px;
    background-color: orange;
    /*text-align: center;*/
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? What do you mean by *clear:left* ?

Comment: I want to put orange div under yellow one. I though when all divs are floating, clear forces next floating elements to not occupy adjacent space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should instead be clearing `#child` and using the `right` value:

```
#child {
    float:right;
    clear: right;
    height:100px;
    width:50px;
    background-color: orange;
    /*text-align: center;*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w5K4j/15/

Comment: OMG, so easy, mistake on my part, I though clearing had to be done in preceding div, but I see you have to indicate it in the following one

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daltonpereira/w5K4j/19/)

Instead of clearing floats inside the element create a class that you can use anytime.

Use `<div class="clearfix"></div>` to clear the floats where ever needed

Below are the changes made to your fiddle

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="unknown"></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div id="child">
    <h3>Click this overflowing text that I'd like to V/H center when rotated</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#unknown {
float:right;
height:50px;
width:20px;
//removed clearance
background-color: yellow
}

.clearfix{clear:both;} //added new class
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/w5K4j/25/

```
#unknown {
float:right;
height:50px;
width:20px;
clear:left;
background-color: yellow;
clear:both; float:none;
}
```